# Inter-environment data migration

Tags: sql-server, migration

At my company we have a need to migrate a portion of our provisional data between versions of our database, housed on different servers (upserts for the most part).  For release management purposes, we have several environments, each containing a slightly different version of our database.  The differences may include additional or missing: columns, constraints, tables, views, etc.  Most importantly, we always have different data (identities representing the same entities may differ across environments as well).

The purpose of our migration requirement is that we'd like to be able to copy data back and forth between environments to stage production changes in our UAT environment, or to copy a particular data scenario/configuration back to our development environment for debugging or testing purposes.

I've read that SSIS is an option, but I'm not sure this applies to my scenario since we would like to leave existing similar (but unrelated) data in-tact.  So far we've achieved our goal via custom migration scripts which use dynamically generated merge statements and by tracking identity values to maintain relationships.  This approach is limited in capability and, without regular maintenance, it quickly falls out of date.

It seems our only viable alternative is spinning up a new SQL instance per configuration, which is an option not well-received by management (due to licensing and maintenance costs primarily).

Is there an easier/lower-maintenance way to transfer only a portion of our data dynamically between environments, while leaving similar but unrelated data in-tact?  Or are we approaching the problem incorrectly?

Comment: Can't move .mdf files? Or detach and attach?

Comment: @McNets Thanks for the suggestion, but this wouldn't satisfy the requirement to preserve existing data in the destination environment.  I'd like to upsert particular data.

Comment: I use SSIS to export some tables to my data warehouse, but for the whole database maybe a log shipping solution is more situable.

Comment: @McNets I'm not very familiar with SSIS, but it sounds like I could sync up specific tables across environments using this approach (probably restricted to provisional/application configuration data).  Log shipping sounds like a total db sync.  Does SSIS work in both directions?  My concern is that new entities are created in each environment independently of the other, these occupy identity values which I need to account for.

Comment: SSIS can works in both directions, but you can get it by using stored procedures and jobs

Comment: @alan the risk is that If you have unique ids like acct numbers etc you'd need to give them new values to avoid duplicates. Child rows would then need to refer to this new value as they are migrated. Its possible but complex. Ssis is no better at this than sql.

Comment: If you have the disk space you could restore a backup to another server and give the db a diferent name. You dont need a new instance license.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the info, I suspected the best option was what I have already done: a custom migration script to (as dynamically as possible) migrate the data as an upsert, tracking ID's to preserve the parent/child relationship.